# Build MVC Route for Blog Categories

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm building a blog and I would like to build a URL based in the company.com/blog/category_name

Until now I have been able only to build with the following route company.com/blog/category/category_name

```
        routes.MapRoute(
            "Blog Category",
            "Blog/Category/{category}",
            new { controller = "Blog", action = "Category" }
        );
```

The Action Link is build like this:

```
  @Html.ActionLink(category.Name, "Category", "Blog", new { category = category.UrlSlug }, new { title = String.Format("See all posts in {0}", category.Name) });
```

How can I change the route so I can achieve the first version?

Comment: Remove the part of the URL that you don't want?

Comment: Hi, thanks. What do you mean by that? I have edit the question with the code that builds the action link

Answer (score 0):

You need something like this:

```
 routes.MapRoute(
       "Blog Category",
        "{controller}/{id}", 
        new { controller = "Blog", 
              action     = "Category", 
              id         =  UrlParameter.Optional
            }
    );
```

Comment: Hi thanks, but I already have the similar default route name: "Default", url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}", is this not the same?